# having issue with numbers in Polymorphic Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

It is said that Church Numbers are encoded as following

```
   c0 = λX. λs:X->X. λz:X. z;
   c1 = λX. λs:X->X. λz:X. s z;
   c2 = λX. λs:X->X. λz:X. s (s z);
   c3 = λX. λs:X->X. λz:X. s (s (s z));
```

The church numbers are terms, right? but the terms are given by the following syntax.

```
  t ::=                          terms
       x                          //variable
       λx:T.t                     //abstraction
       t t                        //application
       λX<:T.t                    //type abstraction
       t [T]                      //type application
```

It seems church numbers do not respect the syntax of terms to me, strange.

I think it should be like

```
      c0 = λX<:some type here. λs:X->X. λz:X. z
```

So, how to write church numbers in a consistent way?

If possible provide simple examples to explain, i.e.  2 * 2, how to write this?

[source[1](http://wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/mmeili_polymorphic_lambda_calculus_final.pdf)](http://wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/mmeili_polymorphic_lambda_calculus_final.pdf)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are misreading syntax. It is likely that you are reading a text which uses some abbreviations. It would help if you gave us a reference where you got the material from. There is no single established way to write the terms of the $\lambda$-calculus. If you are getting this from two different sources, then you should expect that some adjustment to syntax is needed.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Maybe it is a abbreviation as you said. let me check more sources

Comment: No, do not check more sources! Tell us instead what sources you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you written is probably of the System F<sub><:</sub>.

However, the typed Church numerals you written are introduced in the context of System F (a.k.a. λ2) at Fig. 11 of [the source pdf](http://wiki.ifs.hsr.ch/SemProgAnTr/files/mmeili_polymorphic_lambda_calculus_final.pdf).

The terms of System F are defined like below in *Types and programming languages* (Benjamin C. Pierce, MIT press, 2002):

```
t ::=           terms:
      x         variable
      λx:T.t    abstraction
      t t       application
      λX.t      type abstraction
      t [T]     type application
```

The typed Church numerals at Fig. 11 are terms in this definition.

Moreover, in System F<sub><:</sub>, Church numerals are also well-typed and can be more generalized. Below examples are taken from *Types and programming languages*. Top is the maximum type.

```
szero = λX<:Top. λS<:X. λZ<:X. λs:X→S. λz:Z. z;
sone  = λX<:Top. λS<:X. λZ<:X. λs:X→S. λz:Z. s z;
```

Comment: I saw Benjamin's book mentioned an abbreviation " \/X.T =def= \/X<:Top.T ".  I guess that is why. Thanks.